# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' for optional chaining and Nullish coalescing

Tags: node.js, syntax-error, aws-sdk-nodejs, null-coalescing-operator, optional-chaining

The issue was encountered after installing the aws s3 sdk.

I followed the suggested solutions from all other similar problems in the following manner:
-updated node version (even though I had version 18 which supports optional chaining and nullish coalescing)
-installed babel's plugins i.e. both transform and syntax plugins for optional chaining and nullish coalescing

The issue still remains.

snippet of the error is as follows:

```
bodyLengthChecker: config?.bodyLengthChecker ?? util_body_length_node_1.calculateBodyLength,
                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/VGS/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/S3Client.js:19:25)
```

Would really like some assistance here. Please ask me for any information that you require to further clarify the situation.

As mentioned before I tried the suggested solutions, but the issue remained.

Comment: You know the code AWS _runs_ should probably be transpiled before running it, right? Babel really only acts on transforming code, but won't help you when installing. Anyways, we would need node version used by your AWS instance, and probably how you think you are using Babel?

Comment: Yes, Thank you, it was a mix up between the node version in the project vs. on the ubuntu server

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes.Minimum Node version 14 is required for optional chaining

Answer (score 2):

OK so it was a Node issue, I was only using "node -v" to check the version instead of "sudo node -v". Turns out that was outdated.